# How to disable all AJAX requests in a page with jQuery and Javascript ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

I have a page and I would like to disable all AJAX requests with jQuery.

Do you have any ideas? And if it is possible?

```
if (false) {
  //disable all ajax requests
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Do you have access to all the code?

Comment: Use a main var like `disable_all_ajax`  and add a check in all ajax calls. `if(disable_all_ajax === true){ alert('ITS DISABLED MUHAHA');}`

Comment: ````setTimeout(function(){ callback();},9999999);```` ;P

Comment: The website is cached, so even if the server is down the pages are available to the user but the ajax requests will cause Network Error. Yes I have access to all the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all of your ajax requests are being sent through jQuery ajax methods (including helper methods), you can do this with beforeSend.

```
window.ajaxEnabled = true;
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(){ 
        return window.ajaxEnabled; 
    }
});

$.post("http://www.google.com"); // throws an error
window.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.post("http://www.google.com"); // doesn't throw an error
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k2T95/3

---

And here's one that will block all, regardless of what javascript library is sending it, also based on a global flag. Doesn't affect XDomainRequest obj though

```
(function (xhr) {
    var nativeSend = xhr.prototype.send;
    window.ajaxEnabled = true;

    xhr.prototype.send = function () {
        if (window.ajaxEnabled) {
             nativeSend.apply(this, arguments);   
        }
    };
}(window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k2T95/4/

Answer (score 8):

***EDIT:*** There are better ways, depending your specific case which i don't know

Try:  {test it for cross browser support, i didn't do it}

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(){};
```

*Not only for requests done in jQuery*

If you want to re-enable it:

```
var oSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send; // keep reference
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(){};
```

Then call:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = oSend; // get back reference to prototype method
```

Comment: Out of the box, nice. And how to re-anable ?

Comment: I would add it in your answer or we get a follow up question. I don't think OP knows what he's doing here. Maybe some additional Info why this works.

Comment: @nettux443 this stop requests to be send, so there is no success/error/complete callback to be involved

Comment: Just want to confirm it works for Safari and any other WebKit browsers.

Comment: Why is this not marked as the answer? @A.