# Python selenium webdriver - stop a repeating AJAX request

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Here is the procedure to replicate the issue in a browser:
For example, http://www.zulutrade.com/trader/314609?t=30
If you click on "Open Positions" to the right of "Trade History", you will get a repeating AJAX request.

In my code, I need to know how to stop this, after executing:

```
open_pos_table_sel = "#table-view-open-positions+ label"


open_positions_el = br.find_element_by_css_selector(open_pos_table_sel)
br.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", open_positions_el)
```

Which is the code that executes the click via javascript.

Apparently you can disable jQuery with selenium in Java, however I can't find a way to do this in python...

```
selenium.waitForCondition(
        "selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active == 0",
        timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try directly deleting jquery and replacing the xhr send:

```
driver.execute_script("window.oldjQuery=window.jQuery;delete window.jQuery;delete window.$;window.oSend=XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(){console.log('stopped ajax request', arguments)};")
```

And to put jQuery and the xhr send back:

```
driver.execute_script("window.jQuery=window.oldjQuery;window.$=window.jQuery;XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send=window.oSend")
```

with reference from:

- [How to disable all AJAX requests in a page with jQuery and Javascript ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831852/how-to-disable-all-ajax-requests-in-a-page-with-jquery-and-javascript)